# Getting a strict inequality in Holder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

We are given that $g\in L^1([0,1])$ amd $\|g\|_1 > 0$. Additionally, we have a function $f\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ that is nonnegative, has $\|f\|_{\infty} > 0$, and has $\mu(E) = 0$ where $E = \{x:f(x) = \|f\|_{\infty}\}$. I need to show that

$$ \int fg < \|g\|_1\|f\|_{\infty}.$$

Here's what I have so far. We let $A = \{x:f(x) > \|f\|_{\infty}\}$ and $B = \{x: f(x) < \|f\|_{\infty}\}$, then $[0,1] = A \cup B \cup E$, and $\mu(A) = \mu(E) = 0$. So

$$ \int fg = \int_{E^c} fg = \int_B fg.$$

Then we know that on $B$, $f < \|f\|_{\infty}$, so I want to say that

$$ \int_B fg < \int_B\|f\|_{\infty}g,$$

but I don't know that this is true. If this were true, then I would essentially be done, but I'm not sure whether this actually holds. Any suggestions? I haven't used the fats that $g\in L^1$ and $f\in L^{\infty}$, nor the facts that $\|g\|_1 < \infty$ and $\|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$. Perhaps these are useful?

Comment: Is $g$ assumed nonnegative? If not, then the proposed inequality need not hold. (Consider $g = -1$, for example.)

Comment: Note that $\|f\|_{\infty} - f > 0$ on $B$, a set of positive measure. Hence we must have $\|f\|_{\infty}-f > 1/n$ on a set of positive measure, for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: @Bungo It is not required that $g$ be nonnegative. I don't see where $g=-1$ causes an issue. Are you saying that this would give equality?

Comment: I am saying that $\int_B fg < \int_B \|f\|_{\infty} g$ cannot be true if $g = -1$, for in that case the inequality becomes $\int_B f > \int_B \|f\|_{\infty}$. You need absolute values: $\int_B fg \leq \int_B |fg| \leq \int_B \|f\|_{\infty}|g|$.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. So we have $\int_B fg \leq \int_B \|f\|_{\infty}|g| = \|f\|_{\infty}\int_B |g| = \|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_1$, but this does not give us strict inequality, and I don't see where we could have made it strict.

Comment: Do we want to use something along the lines of $(\|f\|_{\infty} -f)|g| >0$ iff $\int_B (\|f\|_{\infty} -f)|g| > 0$?

Comment: We can make it strict as follows. As asserted in my second comment above, there is some set $S$ with positive measure on which $\|f\|_{\infty} - f > 1/n$, or equivalently, $f < \|f\|_{\infty} - 1/n$. Then we have (writing $X = [0,1]$) $\int_X fg \leq \int_X |fg| = \int_S |fg| + \int_{S^c} |fg| \leq \int_S (\|f\|_{\infty} - 1/n)|g| + \int_{S^c}\|f\|_{\infty}|g| = \int_X \|f\|_{\infty}|g| - (1/n)\mu(S) < \int_X \|f\|_{\infty}|g|$.

Comment: Ah thank you! I see it now. I really appreciate your help.